# Problems with binding variables in SQL from shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I need to use bind variables in an SQL query executed from a shell script. Having lots of troubles with it, I started to simplify and ended up with the following;

```
variable ret_val_1 clob
exec select to_char(t.Fecha,'yyyymmddhh24mi')  into :ret_val_1  from MyTable t where t.Column1 = 'A' and rownum <=1
spool &1
select :ret_val_1 from dual;
spool off;
set verify on;
exit;
```

This works fine.

Now, if I try exactly the same code, but using Column2 which is a NUMBER (Column1 is a CHAR), I get the following error:

```
exec select to_char(t.Fecha,'yyyymmddhh24mi')  into :ret_val_1  from MyTable t where t.Column2 = 4 and rownum <=1
```

> SP2-1504: Cannot print uninitialized LOB variable "RET_VAL_1"

When I execute directly:

```
select to_char(t.Fecha,'yyyymmddhh24mi')  
from MyTable t 
where t.Column2 = 4 and rownum <=1*
```

it works perfectly fine!

Any clue?

In the real query, which is much more complex, I have to join both clauses (among others) and use two bind variables as I have to spool them into two different txt files.

Thxs a lot

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Provide sample data and desired results.  The error suggests that no rows match the `where` conditions.

Comment: Assuming you're hitting the same database, check that all data is committed - the session where the plain query works might just be able to see uncommitted data that the script can't. What you've shown works as you'd expect, so if it isn't a data issue, and you haven't just used the wrong column names (hard to tell when you've changed them for posting), add a [mcve] that shows the issue.

Comment: Minor detail, but if you're always selecting a 12-character string, you might try a `varchar2(12)` variable rather than a `clob`.